# How to call in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I want to make a calling app and found out that Voximplant can help me with that.

What do I need to make a call?
Can I make video calls?
What destinations can I call?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation about Voxiplant, there is information about everything you want to know there

[Voxiplant Docs](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/calls/scenario)